# How to communicate simultaneously with an exe using Java process object?

Tags: java, exe, external

Here I am trying to communicate with a chess engine, but every time when I write commands to it with an `OutputStream` object, it never gives any output. Only if I close the output stream it gives an output. However, then the engine stops. How can I resolve this issue please guide me the mistake that I did.

Here is the code:

```java
URL resource = new Object().getClass().getResource("/engine/stockfish.exe");
String path = resource.getPath();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(path);
try {
    Process engine = pb.start();
    InputStream inputStream = engine.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = engine.getOutputStream();
    Thread T = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (engine.isAlive()) {
                    String s = "";
                    while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                        s = s + (char) inputStream.read();
                    }
                    if (!"".equals(s)) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    T.start();
    outputStream.write("isready".getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
//    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I want the program to do is once the engine starts java program needs to write commands to it and read the output while keeping the engine running. In other words, I need to write multiple commands to it.

Comment: What is the delimiter used to indicate distinct commands (i.e., how does the engine know when a full command has been sent)? Does it use e.g., line separators? If so, what happens if you do `outputStream.write("isready\n".getBytes())`?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed it was missing a delimiter at the end.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to consider wrapping the output stream in an `OutputStreamWriter`, so that you can send strings directly without having to call `getBytes()`.